# Are the global C++ I/O objects equivalent or using the C I/O streams?

Tags: c++

I am browsing cppreference for information about the C++ I/O library and understand it all so far, but there is one thing though: For instance, it is said that [std::cout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) is

> associated with the standard C output stream stdout.

what does this mean technically? Is std::cout actually using stdout or does it simply mean that std::cout is functionally equivalent to stdout?

In case that the global objects are using the C streams - why would they use C streams instead of the streams provided by the C++ I/O library?

Comment: associated means a few things...It is common, understood, default and normal to think cout relates to stdout.  BUT it also implies by using the word associated, that the association can be changed

Comment: the fact that [`std::ios::sync_with_stdio()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) exists might give you a hint at how they operate (or might just confuse you further)

Comment: lol. OK I know.  Try this: cout is just a stream.  Its a shortcut to the stdout stream, because its so common to use the stdout 'device'.  Or at least it was very common to send characters to the console, ie stdout.  BUT it is just a stream and cout can be changed to be any stream...Its just a shortcut in many senses

Comment: Why are you curious about this implementation detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "C" streams, these are really the *standard streams* delivered to every *process* by the Operating System.

When a process is created the Operating System creates several low level "file descriptors" that enable *input* and *output* to it.

How these underlying *standard input/output streams* are implemented and in what language is down to the operating system. They have existed in operating systems since *before* the `C` language was written.

Obviously "C" provides access to those through `<stdio.h>` and `C++` provides access to them through `<iostream>`.

I think that to say the `C++` library uses the "C" streams may be a little misleading. If we are talking about the *Standard C Library* then it is unlikely that `C++` will utilize those (but it is required to *cooperate* with them).

The underlying *standard input/output streams* are not part of *Standard C*, but they do have a long history with the `C` language because `C` was created specifically for writing Operating Systems and so the low level core of *Process I/O* is likely to be a `C` library (although it could also be assembler or another language entirely).

For example on `POSIX` systems there are `C` library headers for accessing the low level *standard input/output streams* that are not part of *Standard C*. This maybe why they are referred to as `C` streams in your linked documentation however the concept of standard io streams predates the `C` language itself.

What *Standard C* and *Standard C++* streams do is add layers of *abstraction* on the raw primitives provided by the Operating System. This is generally formatting and converting between numbers and strings, character encodings , etc. `C` and `C++` do those things rather differently.

Comment: So it is C that facilitates the actual I/O operations? C++ simply utilizes the C functionality? Why does the C++ I/O then even define their own stream classes if it relies on the C I/O library anyway?

Comment: @nichlnss I added some more info by way of explanation.

Comment: @nichlnss: How do you print an integer (x) using iostream? `cout << x;` How do you print a double (x) using iostream? `cout << x;`. How do you print an object (x) of a user defined class with several relevant properties using iostream? `cout << x;` -- Now how do you do those same things using the standard C I/O functions? That uniformity is one of the reasons (but not the only one) that the iostream library exists.

Comment: @Galik thank you - that helped. But still, so it actually _is_ the stdio written in C (but yet not part of the standard) that is responsible for the actual low-level I/O operations, whereas the C++ I/O library provides a more high-level functionality to control the low-level things from the stdio? And thus the standard C and C++ streams rely on stdio. Please help me further if you think I might still be slightly confused - you seem clever :))

Comment: @nichlnss If the underlying *process standard io* happens to be a `C` library then that is an implementation detail and not necessarily true. But whatever it is both `C` and `C++` access it independently of one another. `Standard C++` is only required to *cooperate* with `Standard C` it is not required to use its libraries.

Comment: This answer confuses C Standard I/O (stdio.h `FILE*`) with the OS low-level I/O (file descriptors).  stdio.h *is* standard C.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree, I was trying to find better wording. The problem is *standard input/output streams* are used outside of `C`.

Comment: Just read your new edit. "Obviously "C" provides access to those through <stdio.h> and C++ provides access to them through <iostream>" - well, then the citation must mean that std::cout is _equivalent_ and not _using_ stdout. I mean, if <stdio> and <iostream> are equivalents (since they both serve to provide access), right?

Comment: @nichlnss Pretty much. There is confusion though because `stdout` is a `Standard C` term. This is what Ben Voight was telling me about terminology. Both `C` and `C++` use the same, underlying **standard input and output**. These are low level objects. On `POSIX` systems they are simply the integer numbers `0` and `1`. I have no idea how they are represented under Windows.